# Signed vs has signed / first vs the first

Tags: present-perfect

I have a few dilemmas regarding grammar, and would like you to help me improve my written English, by fixing errors and explained me rules.

It's for a project, the sentence would be like this:

> Member states with at least one university (HAS?) signed a Memorandum
>   (it is some formal paper) and member states with no universities
>   (HAVE?) signed a Memorandum.

Is this correct? Should I put has/have signed? What's the difference?

Other sentence would be:

> First number represents a number of
>   universities which shortlisted candidates and second number represents
>   a total number of universities per country.

When should I put **the** first, **the** second?

Answer (score 1):

> - Member states with at least one university **have** signed a memorandum.
> - Member states with no universities **have** signed a memorandum.

In both cases, the main subject is the compound noun "member states." This is plural. The restrictive clause that follows ("... with at least one university") has no bearing on the grammatical number of the subject. So, correct subject-verb agreement calls for **have**. When, as in this case, a restrictive clause contains an element with a different grammatical number than the main subject, the result may sound strange to some ears. But it is correct.

> When should I put the first, the second?

You need it here.

> **The** first number represents **the** number of universities which shortlisted candidates, and **the** second represents **the** total number of universities per country.

This is also a little awkward: it's not necessary to say that a number "represents" another number. You can just say that it *is* that number.

Comment: Thank you very much!
One small remark regarding the first part: it is not countries that sign a memorandum, but universities (this sentence also sounds weird, is it correct?), to I think we shall stick with "has" for university as a subject.

Comment: Also, if you can check these two sentences as well, I would be very grateful.


Member states with a university which signed a memorandum, but did not shortlist candidates are...

Member states with no universities signed a memorandum are ...